# asp.net radio button on click java script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

in the following code i have a html radio and a java script code. when the radio is checked the text of Lable1 text will be change to "test".
my question is that how can i do the same thing for asp:radiobutton that run on client side?

```
 <input id="Radio1" checked="true" onmousedown="fun()" name="R1" type="radio"         
value="V1" /></p>
<script>
function fun()
{
 document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML.text = "test";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is classic ASP you could use this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server" onclick="fun();">

            <asp:ListItem Text="JavaScript" Value="JavaScript</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="C#" Value="C#"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="ASP.Net" Value="ASP.Net"></asp:ListItem>

</asp:RadioButtonList>


<script type='text/javascript'>

function fun()
{
 document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML.text = "test";

}

</script>
```

I would recommend using the onchange event if this is just html and javascript:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange

Answer (score 0):

Set the ClientIDMode to "Static" so the ID doesn't change.

```
<asp:RadioButton id="R1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" onmousedown="fun()" Value = "V1"></asp:RadioButton>
```

I only know how to do it using Jquery, so your script block would look like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>       
    function fun() {
        $('label[for="R1"]').text('your new text');

    }
</script>
```

Comment: <asp:RadioButton> does not have a onmousedown event

Comment: the mousedown event is a jquery event handler, not webforms.